# Why does !! in Python run commands but encase the output in brackets

Tags: python, ipython

A typeo produced an unexpected result and just in case it has a use, I want to understand it.

`!!C:/myPythonPath/python script/event.py`

Single `!` runs a command (DOS, LINUX, other commands you could normally execute from a command line) from within Python, in this case, from with a Jupyter Notebook cell of Python 2.7.

I mistakenly typed two exclamation points and surprisingly, the code still worked, but my output appeared inside of square brackets as in:

`[ output of my program ]`

What's more, the presentation looks like it put the output in a list.  Here is an example:

```
['------------------------------',
 'Unknown Event: Django Girls Bucaramanga, Colombia',
 '    Time    :  08 April &ndash; 09 April  2017',
 '    Location: Bucaramanga, Colombia',
 '------------------------------',
 'Upcoming Event: Python ... ]
```

If this is truly a list, is there a way to capture it for later use in a program that is calling a script?  I tried adding in an x = into the original line, but this did not work for me.  Maybe I did not set up the line right.  Is there a way to do this? This is just a point of curiosity.

Comment: Googling [`IPython double exclamation`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/reference.html#manual-capture-of-command-output-and-magic-output) or [`Jupyter double exclamation`](https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/ipython-jupyter#gs.ImXit1s) turns up the answer immediately.

Comment: sometimes its all in how you search.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments provided by @user2357112 held the answer. Admittedly, you have to find it in a sea of other useful topics, and the actual syntax to solve the problem is not clearly stated in the write-ups.

The answer:  Yes, `!!` does convert output of `!` into a list.  But attempts to capture it from `!!`, as the links below indicate is possible, do not seem to work.

Again from @user2357112, this syntax (which does not use the `!!`) will achieve the desired effect (run the command and capture it in a list):

`x = %sx echo "some text"`

Print `x` and you will get:
`["some text"]`

Links for more reading so they don't get buried in the comments:

1. https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/ipython-jupyter#gs.ImXit1s
2. https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/reference.html#manual-capture-of-command-output-and-magic-output

Comment: Unless things have changed, you can't actually capture `!!` output in a variable, which makes it kind of weird that the syntax even exists. To capture the list, you need to use the `%sx` magic: `x = %sx echo "some text"`.

Comment: Test the code above on Python 2.7 and you might see why I thought it worked.  On first run, it did what was expected.  On re-run, I get an error that echo is not recognized stored in the variable.  Python has this weird way of working even when code is broken once or twice and then surprising you later.  Going to d osome more testing and then decide whether to edit or delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

All the details here -> https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-sx

copy/paste:

```
     %sx¶
    
        Shell execute - run shell command and capture output (!! is short-hand).
    
        %sx command
    
        IPython will run the given command using commands.getoutput(), and

 return the result formatted as a list (split on ‘n’). Since the output is
 
_returned_, it will be stored in ipython’s regular output cache Out[N] and in 

the ‘_N’ automatic variables.
```

I performed some tests (full code below so you can check yourself)

```
str_x="some text x"
str_y="some text y"
str_z="some text z"

%sx echo {str_x} ;echo -e {str_x}
_
x = %sx echo {str_x}; echo {str_x}
x
!echo {str_y}; echo {str_y}
y = !echo {str_y}; echo {str_y}
y
!!echo {str_z}; echo {str_z}
_
z = !!echo {str_z}; echo {str_z}
_
z
```

Individual outputs (python 3.7)

[image]

Some conclusions:

- `!!` is a shortcut for `%sx`
- `!!` cannot be assigned to variable, but the ouput is on `_`
- `!` and `%sx` can be assigned to a variable, in any case ouput is on `_`
- `!` output is natural, while `%sx` output is a list of the output (the output converted to a list)

If you look at the first link, `%sx` is a special case for `%sc`.

> %sx differs from %sc in that %sx automatically splits into a list,
> like ‘%sc -l’. The reason for this is to make it as easy as possible
> to process line-oriented shell output via further python commands. %sc
> is meant to provide much finer control, but requires more typing.

Note: Don't be fooled by the last `_`. The command before it failed, so what it stores is the output of the previous one.

```
!!echo {str_z}; echo {str_z}
_
z = !!echo {str_z}; echo {str_z}
_  # This one is not the output of the preceding line
z
```